# Filtering and matching with an elasticsearch query

Tags: elasticsearch

I am having trouble applying a secondary filter to my elasticsearch query below. Only the first filter is matching. I want both filters to apply to the query.

```
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "filter": {
              "range": {
                "@timestamp": {
                  "gte": "2019-03-12",
                  "lte": "2019-03-13"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "filter": {
              "bool": {
                "must": {
                  "match": {
                    "msg_text": "foo AND bar"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

Comment: Could you share the mapping and sample document. The query works fine if the field `msg_text` is of type `text`.

Answer (score 1):

Well I've mentioned two solutions, first one makes use of [Match Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html) while the second one makes use of [Query String](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html).

Also I'm assuming `msg_text` field is of type `text`.

Difference is that, [`query_string`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#query-dsl-query-string-query) uses a parser, that would parse the text you mention based on the operators like `AND, OR`.

While [`match query`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html) would read the text, analyse the text and based on it constructs a `bool` query. In the sense *you don't need to mention operators and it won't work*

You can read more about them in the links I've mentioned.

### 1. Using Match Query

```
POST <your_index_name>/_search
{  
   "query":{  
      "bool":{  
         "filter":{  
            "bool":{  
               "must":[  
                  {  
                     "range":{  
                        "@timestamp":{  
                           "gte":"2019-03-12",
                           "lte":"2019-03-13"
                        }
                     }
                  },
                  {  
                     "match":{  
                        "msg_text":"foo bar"         
                     }
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

### 2. Using Query String

```
POST <your_index_name>/_search
{  
   "query":{  
      "bool":{  
         "filter":{  
            "bool":{  
               "must":[  
                  {  
                     "range":{  
                        "@timestamp":{  
                           "gte":"2019-03-12",
                           "lte":"2019-03-13"
                        }
                     }
                  },
                  {  
                     "query_string":{  
                        "fields": ["msg_text"],    <----- You can add more fields here using comma as delimiter
                        "query":"foo AND bar"
                     }
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Technically nothing is wrong with your solution, in the sense, it would work, but I hope my answers clear, simplifies the query and helps you understand what you are trying to do.

Let me know if it helps!